# Post to my facebook page (fan site) as admin via php (fb sdk) with extended token

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

**What is the simplest way to achieve the following task?**

I've got a website where users can upload some kind of posts. I need a new feature: when someone publishing a post, it would appear in my websites' fan page too as a facebook post from the administrator of the page (aka in the name of page), even if I am offline. To create this new function I would like to use FB PHP SDK 3.x and long-lived token.

All the solutions I found are outdated (using offline_access permission), using curl without FB SDK and not contains answer how to extend short-lived access token programatically, or publish the post to some others' wall, etc.